# Unable to handle 403 (forbidden) in RXJS pipe, map

Tags: javascript, rxjs, http-status-code-403, rxjs6

I have some code that goes to my server and returns some data. I have noticed, that i am unable to catch/handle a 403 response.

Code:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteRequest, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable <boolean> {

    return this.myService.getEntitlements()
        .pipe(
            map(data => {
                this.isEntitled = data.hasEntitlements;

                if(this.isEntitled === true) {
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            }),
            catchError((err: any) => {
                return of(false);
            })       

        };
}
```

Comment: you got to show the getEntitlements() code

Comment: Please provide more informations. What actually happens when you get a 403 ?